# Como imprimir os dados em uma lista dinâmica duplamente encadeada em C?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Boa tarde, pessoal. Está é minha primeira pergunta aqui no site, então sugestões são bem vindas. 
Estou escrevendo um código utilizando Lista Dinâmica Duplamente Encadeada para a aula de Estrutura de Dados da faculdade e estou tendo bastante dificuldade em imprimir a lista para ver se os valores foram atribuídos corretamente. A maioria dos exemplos que encontro na internet são feitos de forma diferente a qual meu professor pede, poderiam me ajudar?
Já tentei variações na função, porém: ou o compilador trava ou é impresso somente o último valor inserido.
Segue o código escrito em C no CodeBlocks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct elemento {
    int info;
    struct elemento *prox;
    struct elemento *ant;
};
typedef struct elemento tipoElemento;

struct estruturaLDDE{
    tipoElemento *primeiro;
    tipoElemento *ultimo;
    int tamanhoLista;
};
typedef struct estruturaLDDE tipoLDDE;

void inicializaLista (tipoLDDE *listaAux){
    listaAux->primeiro = NULL;
    listaAux->ultimo = NULL;
    listaAux->tamanhoLista=0;
}
void insereElementoFinal (tipoLDDE *listaAux){
    tipoElemento *novo = (tipoElemento*) malloc(sizeof(tipoElemento));
    int n, m;
    for(n=0;n<10;n++){
        printf("digite o numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &novo->info);
        if (listaAux->tamanhoLista == 0){
            novo->prox = NULL;
            novo->ant = NULL;
            listaAux->primeiro=novo;
            listaAux->ultimo=novo;
        }
        else{
            novo->prox = NULL;
            novo->ant = listaAux->ultimo;
            listaAux->ultimo->prox = novo;
            listaAux->ultimo=novo;
        }
        listaAux->tamanhoLista++;
    }
}
/*void libera(tipoLDDE *eli){
    tipoLDDE *no = eli, *aux;
    while (no != NULL){
        aux = no;
        no->ultimo = no->ultimo->prox;
        free (aux);
    }
    eli = NULL;
}*/
void imprime(tipoLDDE *b){
    tipoLDDE *a;
    a->ultimo=b->ultimo->prox;
    int i;
    if(a->ultimo == NULL) printf("a lista esta vazia");
    else{
        while(a->ultimo != NULL){
           printf("%i\n", a->ultimo->info);
           a->ultimo=a->ultimo->prox;
        }
    }
    printf("%i", a->tamanhoLista);
}

int main(){
    tipoLDDE *li= (tipoLDDE*) malloc(sizeof(tipoLDDE));
    printf("-------BEM VINDO AO JOGO DE SOMA 12-------\n");
    inicializaLista(li);
    insereElementoFinal(li);
    imprime(li);
   // libera(li);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fernando, seu primeiro erro é na função `insereElementoFinal`. Você está alocando espaço na memória para o nodo apenas uma vez. Você precisa alocar uma vez para cada valor que você vai armazenar, então ao invés de inicializar `novo` no inicio da função, dentro do `for` você deveria alocar um novo espaço na memória e atribuir a posição desse espaço à `novo` a cada iteração.

```
void insereElementoFinal(tipoLDDE *listaAux) {
    int n, m;
    tipoElemento *novo;

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        novo = (tipoElemento*) malloc(sizeof(tipoElemento));
        printf("digite o numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &novo->info);

        if (listaAux->tamanhoLista == 0) {
            novo->prox = NULL;
            novo->ant = NULL;
            listaAux->primeiro=novo;
            listaAux->ultimo=novo;
        } else {
            novo->prox = NULL;
            novo->ant = listaAux->ultimo;
            listaAux->ultimo->prox = novo;
            listaAux->ultimo = novo;
        }

        listaAux->tamanhoLista++;
    }
}
```

Agora para percorrer a lista, não entendi direito qual era a sua ideia com o código postado. Você só precisava criar uma variável auxiliar com o mesmo tipo do seu nodo, e reatribui-la para o próximo valor até que o próximo valor seja `NULL`, ou seja, até o final da lista.

```
void imprime(tipoLDDE *b) {
    tipoElemento *aux = b->primeiro;

    if (aux == NULL) {
        printf("A lista esta vazia");
    } 

    while (aux != NULL) {
        printf("%i\n", aux->info);
        aux = aux->prox;
    }

    printf("Tamanho da lista: %i", b->tamanhoLista);
}
```

Deu para entender a lógica?

Comment: Entendi sim, até sanou outra dúvida que eu tinha. Porém só está sendo impressa a variável "tamanhoLista". Será que fiz algo errado?

Comment: Você alterou alguma outra parte do código? [Aqui](https://repl.it/repls/DisloyalFinishedReentrant) tem ele da mesma forma que foi postado e está funcionando.

Comment: Agora funcionou! Copiei o código novamente e fiz as alterações sugeridas e deu certo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!